# What is the syntax for the LIMIT function work in SQL?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am new to SQL, so I thought I'd practice some functions in BigQuery on a public dataset. I am a bit confused in regards to how to properly use the LIMIT function. Is it supposed to be the last function in the query?

I tried to use the ORDER BY function, but I ran into some trouble with the LIMIT function. At first, when I put the ORDER BY after the LIMIT, it didn't work (I got a syntax error) even though the number of rows in the dataset is smaller than the limit, then when I removed the LIMIT entirely, the query ran alright, and when I put the LIMIT after the ORDER BY, it also ran normally.
Any assistance is greatly appreciated, I will put the code for my attempts below:
1st attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_cfe.datacenter_cfe`
LIMIT 1000
ORDER BY year
```

2nd attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_cfe.datacenter_cfe` 
ORDER BY year
```

3rd attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM `bigquery-public-data.google_cfe.datacenter_cfe` 
ORDER BY year
LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: Do you want the 1000 first rows (year wise), or do you want to order 1000 random rows by year?

Comment: @jarlh You may be onto something, I think I misunderstood the question because OP seem to think first exemple and 3rd exemple should return different results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keywords in SQL have a specific order in which they are meant to be used.

The  order is :

1. SELECT
2. FROM
3. JOIN
4. WHERE
5. GROUP BY
6. HAVING
7. ORDER BY
8. LIMIT

EDIT :
If you're trying to sort on arbitrary data instead sorting and then limiting the result set. There are multiple ways to go at this, but the query will most likely be less efficient.

(for exemple you could query on a subquery, but you lose access to any indexes so this is only viable for very small LIMIT)

Depending on why you're trying to do this a different approach might be better than an other.

Comment: You forgot HAVING.

Answer (score 0):

The specific syntax for the LIMIT clause varies depending on the SQL database system you are using. Here are some common SQL database systems and their syntax for limiting rows:

1. MySQL / MariaDB:

   SELECT column1, column2
   FROM table_name
   LIMIT number_of_rows;

For example, to retrieve the first 10 rows from a table named employees:

```
SELECT * FROM employees
LIMIT 10;
```

2. PostgreSQL:

   SELECT column1, column2 FROM table_name LIMIT number_of_rows;

PostgreSQL uses the same syntax as MySQL and MariaDB for the LIMIT clause.

3. SQLite:

   SELECT column1, column2
   FROM table_name
   LIMIT number_of_rows OFFSET offset;

SQLite allows you to specify an optional OFFSET in addition to the LIMIT. This is useful for pagination. For example, to retrieve rows 11-20:

SELECT * FROM employees
LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10;

4. SQL Server (starting from SQL Server 2012):

SQL Server uses the OFFSET and FETCH clauses for paging.

```
SELECT column1, column2
FROM table_name
ORDER BY some_column
OFFSET offset_value ROWS
FETCH NEXT number_of_rows ROWS ONLY;
```

For example, to retrieve the second set of 10 rows:

```
SELECT * FROM employees
ORDER BY employee_id
OFFSET 10 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY;
```